# Intercept right-click on URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm developing a site that uses ajax to load content in, but I also provide semantic links to the actual ajax page for browsers with JS disabled:

```
<a href="/products/car.html">Show Cars</a>

$("a").click(function(){
$("#main").load('/products/car.html');
return false;
});
```

If a user right-clicks/command-clicks and copies the URL (`www.mysite.com/products/car.html`) to share with a friend, is there a way for me to intercept that link in jQuery and exceute a function?

`if window.location == 'www.mysite.com/products/car.html' > Do This` ?

Answer (score 2):

why not?

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://mysite.com/products/cars.html')
{
    doSomething ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the user from manually typing in a new URL in their browser bar via JavaScript.

However, in your car.html source, (you'd probably need car.php or something instead, depending on your server side code), you could test the [request headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) to determine the "Accepts" value.

- If it's something like "text/javascript" or "application/json", then simply send the JSON content as you normally would.
- If it's something else (like "text/html"), then redirect them to this page that loads the JSON content, with the car.html content as the default-loaded content.

**Edit:**  I might have misunderstood a bit.  When the car.html page loads, there's nothing to stop you from executing JavaScript on page load to check the current URL & redirect the user elsewhere.